# Reading, Writing, and Proving Math: Cartesian Product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

The following is my attempt at one of my homework assignments.

> Let A, B, and C be sets. If the statement below is true, prove it. If false, give a counter example.
>
> A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C) = (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C).

I want to say this is true so I went about it as follows.
To do this, I needed to show that they are subsets of each other.

Claim 1: A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C) $\subseteq$ (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C)

Let z $\in$ A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C) $\rightarrow$ z = (x,y) $\in$ A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C)

$\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ (B $\cap$ C)

$\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\wedge$ (y $\in$ B $\wedge$ y $\in$ C)

$\rightarrow$ (x $\in$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ B) $\wedge$ (x $\in$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ C)

$\rightarrow$ (x,y) $\in$ A $\times$ B $\wedge$ (x,y) $\in$ A $\times$ C

$\rightarrow$ (x,y) $\in$ (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C)

Thus A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C) $\subseteq$ (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C)

Claim 2: (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C) $\subseteq$ A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C)

Let z $\in$ (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C) $\rightarrow$ z =(x,y) $\in$ (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C)

$\rightarrow$ (x,y) $\in$ (A $\times$ B) $\wedge$ (x,y) $\in$ (A $\times$ C)

Suppose (x,y) $\in$ (A $\times$ B)

$\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ B

$\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\cap$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ B $\cap$ C

$\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ B $\cap$ C

$\rightarrow$ (x,y) $\in$ A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C)

Suppose (x,y) $\in$ (A $\times$ C)

$\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ C

$\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\cap$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ B $\cap$ C

$\rightarrow$ x $\in$ A $\wedge$ y $\in$ B $\cap$ C

$\rightarrow$ (x,y) $\in$ A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C)

Thus (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C) $\subseteq$ A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C)

Hence A $\times$ (B $\cap$ C) = (A $\times$ B) $\cap$ (A $\times$ C).

The only think I am not sure of is the second Claim. What makes me have doubts is the fact y can be in B but what if it is not in C. Then I thought, well doesn't y have to be in both to begin with. This is when I got confused.

Thanks for taking the time to read the post. Thanks in advanced for your feedback.

Comment: By the way, I don't think it's a good idea to use the symbol "$\to$" ("implies") every time you want to say "therefore."  The meaning of "Suppose $P \to Q$" is not the same as "Suppose $P$. Therefore $Q$" even if you put a period and a line break before the "$\to$".

Answer (score 2):

The first half of the argument is correct. The second isn’t quite correct as its written: the step from $x\in A\land y\in B$ to $x\in A\cap A\land y\in B\cap C$ needs to be justified, since up to that point you’ve not said that $y\in C$. I’d do it like this:

> Let $z\in(A\times B)\cap(A\times C)$. Then $z=\langle x,y\rangle$ for some $x$ and $y$, and $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times B$ and $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times C$. Since $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times B$, we know that $x\in A$ and $y\in B$; and since $\langle x,y\rangle\in A\times C$, we also know that $x\in A$ and $y\in C$. Since $y\in B$ and $y\in C$, we have $y\in B\cap C$, so $z=\langle x,y\rangle \in A\times(B\cap C)$, as desired.

Note that in general proofs are easier to read when written as prose — technical prose, to be sure, often with lots of mathematical symbols, but still prose — rather than as extended logical calculations.

Comment: Note that in general I definitely find calculations easier to read than prose.  Note that I was taught by [Dijkstra](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/)/[Scholten](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-0-387-96957-2)/[van Gasteren](http://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-3-540-52849-4), [Gries/Schneider](https://www.springer.com/computer/theoretical+computer+science/book/978-0-387-94115-8), Back (["structured derivations"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structured_derivations) ), [Hehner](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hehner/).

Answer (score 1):

You say "suppose $(x,y) \in A\times B$", but it's already in there by assumption if it's in $A\times B \cap A\times C$.

$→ x ∈ A ∧ y ∈ B \\
→ x ∈ A ∩ A ∧ y ∈ B ∩ C$

This part here doesn't make sense.

What I would do is assume $(x,y) \in (A\times B) \cap (A\times C)$.  Then $(x,y) \in A\times B $ and $(x,y) \in A\times C$.  So $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ and $x\in A$ and $y \in C$ so $(x,y) \in A \times (B\cap C)$.

Answer (score 1):

$(a,z)\in A\times (B\cap C)$ iff $a\in A$ and $z\in B\cap C.$

$z\in B\cap C$ iff $z\in B$ and $z\in C$.

$a\in A$ and $z\in B$ iff $(a,z)\in A\times B$.

$a\in A$ and $z\in C$ iff $(a,z)\in A\times C$.

$(a,z)\in A\times B$ and $(a,z)\in A\times C$ iff $(a,z)\in (A\times B) \cap (A\times C).$

Answer (score 0):

*This is not a comment on your proof but an alternative way to approach problems like this.*

Here is yet another way to prove more easily, and more formally at the same time.  Starting on the most complex side, we calculate which elements $\;p\;$ are in this set: just we expand the definitions and simplify, and then work back to our goal:
\begin{align}
& p \in (A \times B) \cap (A \times C) \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& p \in A \times B \;\land\; p \in A \times C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\times\;$, twice"} \\
& \text{ispair}(p) \land \text{fst}(p) \in A \land \text{snd}(p) \in B \;\land\; \text{ispair}(p) \land \text{fst}(p) \in A \land \text{snd}(p) \in C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"logic: simplify"} \\
& \text{ispair}(p) \;\land\; \text{fst}(p) \in A \;\land\; \text{snd}(p) \in B \land \text{snd}(p) \in C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\cap\;$"} \\
& \text{ispair}(p) \;\land\; \text{fst}(p) \in A \;\land\; \text{snd}(p) \in B \cap C \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\;\times\;$"} \\
& p \in A \times (B \cap C)
\end{align}
By set extensionality this proves the original statement.